Asyncronous Lazy Logging for Maven Project
Short Question:
How to achieve lazy logging where Suppliers<> are executed inside the AsyncAppender thread instead of the main thread?
Long Explanation:
Current logging calls with AsyncAppender I have
log.info("The data is {}", veryHeavyMethodForMaskingData(data)); // this method consumes 50% of the API time. 

Although FluentAPI with logback provide suppliers based calls (sample below), the suppliers are resolved before reaching asyncAppender, in the main thread. Hence below is similar as above in terms of execution.
logger.atInfo().setMessage("The data is {}").addArgument( ()->veryHeavyMethodForMaskingData(data) ).log();

source: https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#fluent

I have tried Logback and Log4j2 implementations, but could not get to desired result.
